# Session out unexpectedly, even with session out time is 360

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application, when click menu "MyAccount(It'll navigate to agentadmin.cs file)" I'm getting session timing out. I have set session time to "360" also I am not able to find the session out every time, some times it's showing.

Scenario is if you wait on the Quick Quote screen (getquote.aspx) for a minute or two, then attempt to click the My Account it might cause the problem and display the “You must be Logged in…” screen.

**MyParentBase.cs**

```
public class MyParentBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public MyParentBase()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    protected void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exp = Server.GetLastError();
        new CustomErrors(exp);
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        //Check the User Objec in the Session
        //If User object does not exist in the Session then Redirect to the Login Page..
        if (Session["User"] == null)
         {
             Session.RemoveAll();
             Session.Abandon();
             HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("loginmessage.aspx", false);
             //Response.Redirect("Index.aspx", false);
             Response.End();
             //ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "clientScript", "alert('Invalid Agent ID or Password')", true);
         }
    }

    public void SetSecureProtocol(bool IsSecure)
    {
        string redirectURl = null;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request != null)
        {

            if (IsSecure && !HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                redirectURl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
            }
            else if (!IsSecure && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                redirectURl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("https:", "http:");
            }

            if (redirectURl != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectURl);
            }
        }
    }

    public void RedirectFromLogin()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] == null)
        {
            Session.RemoveAll();
            Session.Abandon();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("loginmessage.aspx", false);
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Index.aspx", false);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            //ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "clientScript", "alert('Invalid Agent ID or Password')", true);
        }
    }


}
```

**AgentAdmin.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class AgentAdmin : MyParentBase
{
    string ErrorMsg = string.Empty;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"]) == "Site")
        {
            SetSecureProtocol(true);
        }
        #region Bind AgentAdmin Style Sheet
        HtmlLink cssLink = new HtmlLink();
        cssLink.Href = "../Css/agentadmin.css";
        cssLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
        cssLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
        Header.Controls.Add(cssLink);
        #endregion
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                BindAgentData();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }

    public void BindAgentData()
    {
        # region Bind the data from Agent table
        try
        {
            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentBusinessName)) != "")
                lblBusiinessName.Text = Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentBusinessName));
            else
                lblBusiinessName.Text = "";
            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentFirstName)) != "")
                lblFirstName.Text = Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentFirstName));
            else
                lblFirstName.Text = "";
            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentLastName)) != "")
                lblLastName.Text = Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentLastName));
            else
                lblLastName.Text = "";
            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentAddress)) != "")
                lblAdress.Text = Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentAddress));
            else
                lblAdress.Text = "";
            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentCity)) != "")
                lblCity.Text = Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentCity));
            else
                lblCity.Text = "";
            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentStateID)) != "")
                lblState.Text = Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentStateID));
            else
                lblState.Text = "";
            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentZipCode)) != "")
                lblZipcode.Text = Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentZipCode));
            else
                lblZipcode.Text = "";
            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentPhoneNumber)) != "")
                lblPhone.Text = Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentPhoneNumber));
            else
                lblPhone.Text = "";
            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentFaxNumber)) != "")
                lblFax.Text = Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentFaxNumber));
            else
                lblFax.Text = "";
            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentEmail)) != "")
                lblEmail.Text = Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentEmail));
            else
                lblEmail.Text = "";
            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentFedIDSS)) != "")
                lblFederal.Text = Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentFedIDSS));
            else
                lblFederal.Text = "";
            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentUserName)) != "")
                lblUserName.Text = Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentUserName));
            else
                lblUserName.Text = "";
            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentPass)) != "")
                lblPassword.Text = "*******";
            else
                lblPassword.Text = "";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        # endregion
    }

    protected void lbtnAgree_Onclick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //print the AgentAgreement pdf by gselvam
        try
        {
            #region print the AgentAgreement pdf using Itextsharp

            int AgentId = 0;

            if (Convert.ToString((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentID)) != "")
                AgentId = Convert.ToInt32((((Agent)(Session["User"])).AgentID));
            Agent AgentVar = new Agent();
            AgentVar.AgentID = Convert.ToInt32(AgentId);
            UserBobj UserBobjVar = new UserBobj(AgentVar);
            AgentVar = UserBobjVar.LoadAgentByPrimaryKey();

            string FileName = "AgentAgreement_";

            if (AgentVar.AgentBusinessName != "")
            {
                FileName = "AgentAgreement_" + AgentVar.AgentBusinessName;
            }
            else if (AgentVar.AgentFirstName != "" && AgentVar.AgentFirstName != null)
            {
                FileName = "AgentAgreement_" + AgentVar.AgentFirstName + AgentVar.AgentLastName;
            }


            string AgentBusinessOrFL = string.Empty;

            if (AgentVar.AgentBusinessName != "" && AgentVar.AgentBusinessName != null)
            {
                AgentBusinessOrFL = Convert.ToString(AgentVar.AgentBusinessName);
            }
            else
            {
                if (AgentVar.AgentFirstName != "" && AgentVar.AgentFirstName != null)
                    AgentBusinessOrFL = Convert.ToString(AgentVar.AgentFirstName).Trim() + " ";
                else
                    AgentBusinessOrFL = "" + " ";

                if (AgentVar.AgentLastName != "" && AgentVar.AgentLastName != null)
                    AgentBusinessOrFL += Convert.ToString(AgentVar.AgentLastName).Trim();
                else
                    AgentBusinessOrFL += "";
            }

            string AgentAddress = string.Empty;
            if (AgentVar.AgentAddress != "" && AgentVar.AgentAddress != null)
                AgentAddress = Convert.ToString(AgentVar.AgentAddress);
            else
                AgentAddress = " ";

            string AgentCityStateZip = string.Empty;
            if (AgentVar.AgentCity != "" && AgentVar.AgentCity != null)
                AgentCityStateZip = Convert.ToString(AgentVar.AgentCity) + ", ";
            else
                AgentCityStateZip = " " + ", ";
            if (AgentVar.AgentStateID != "" && AgentVar.AgentStateID != null)
                AgentCityStateZip += Convert.ToString(AgentVar.AgentStateID) + " ";
            else
                AgentCityStateZip += " " + " ";
            if (AgentVar.AgentZipCode != "" && AgentVar.AgentZipCode != null)
                AgentCityStateZip += Convert.ToString(AgentVar.AgentZipCode);
            else
                AgentCityStateZip += " ";

            string AgentBusinessName = string.Empty;

            if (AgentVar.AgentBusinessName != "" && AgentVar.AgentBusinessName != null)
                AgentBusinessName = Convert.ToString(AgentVar.AgentBusinessName);
            else
                AgentBusinessName = " ";

            string AgentName = string.Empty;
            if (AgentVar.AgentFirstName != "" && AgentVar.AgentFirstName != null)
                AgentName = Convert.ToString(AgentVar.AgentFirstName).Trim() + " ";
            else
                AgentName = "" + " ";

            if (AgentVar.AgentLastName != "" && AgentVar.AgentLastName != null)
                AgentName += Convert.ToString(AgentVar.AgentLastName).Trim();
            else
                AgentName += "";


            string Inputfile = "~/InputPdf/AutoWarrantyAgentAgreement.pdf";
            Inputfile = Server.MapPath(Inputfile);
            string Outputfile = string.Empty;
            Com.Thylak.CommonMethods.CommonMethods CommonMethodsVar = new Com.Thylak.CommonMethods.CommonMethods();
            string MentionAnUser = CommonMethodsVar.LoadUserIdByUserInterface();
            Outputfile = Server.MapPath("~/Output/") + FileName + MentionAnUser + ".pdf";

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Inputfile);
            int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(Outputfile, FileMode.Create));
            AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
            fields.SetField("PDF_DateEntered", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", AgentVar.AgentDateEntered));
            fields.SetField("PDF_AgentBusinessName", AgentBusinessOrFL);
            fields.SetField("PDF_AgentAddress", AgentAddress);
            fields.SetField("PDF_AgentCityStateZip", AgentCityStateZip);
            fields.SetField("PDF_DateEntered", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", AgentVar.AgentDateEntered));
            fields.SetField("PDF_AgentBusinessName", AgentBusinessOrFL);
            fields.SetField("PDF_AgentName", AgentName);
            fields.SetField("PDF_DateEntered", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", AgentVar.AgentDateEntered));
            stamper.FormFlattening = true;
            stamper.Close();
            //string filepath = Outputfile;
            string filename = FileName;
            string filepath = "~/Output/" + FileName + MentionAnUser + ".pdf";
            Application["Path"] = filepath;
            if ((File.Exists(Server.MapPath(filepath))))
            {
                string PageURl = "AutoWarrantyAgencyPDF.aspx";
                string popupScript = "<script language='javascript'>" +
                           "window.open('" + PageURl + "', 'popup','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=800,height=500,left=100,top=100');" +
                            "</script>";

                Page.RegisterStartupScript("PopupScript", popupScript);
            }

            //if (File.Exists(imag_path))
            //{
            //    PdfBobj f_down = new PdfBobj(filename);
            //    string type = f_down.Downloader();
            //    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
            //    if (type != "")
            //    {
            //        Response.ContentType = type;
            //    }
            //    Response.WriteFile(imag_path, true);
            //    Response.Flush();
            //    FileInfo FileDel = new FileInfo(imag_path);
            //    FileDel.Delete();
            //    Response.End();

            //}
            #endregion
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMsg = "An Error occured while processing your request : ";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
                        typeof(AgentAdmin), "ERROR_DIALOG",
                        string.Format("alert('{0}');", ErrorMsg), true);
        }
    }

    protected void lbEdit_Onclick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("EditAgentAdmin.aspx", false);
    }

}
```

Comment: One suspected could be the InProcess session together with restarting IIS pool. It could happen if your app consumes too much of memory (and there is some limit)... So, try to move the session from InProce into separated Session process

Comment: what is the unit of that 360? (min/sec/hrs) ?